# Large sparse linear system solving with SimplicialCholesky Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I am actually trying to solve large sparse linear systems using C++ lib Eigen. 
Sparse matrices are taken from this [page](https://sparse.tamu.edu/). Each system as this structure: `Ax = b` where `A` is the sparse matrix (n x n), `b` is computed as `A*xe` with `xe` vector of dimension n containing only zeros. After computing `x` I need to compute the relative error between `xe` and `x`. I have written some code but I can't understand why the relative error is so high (1.49853e+08) at the end of the computation.

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>
#include<Eigen/SparseCholesky>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;


int main()
{

    SparseMatrix<double> mat;
    loadMarket(mat, "/Users/anto/Downloads/ex15/ex15.mtx");

 VectorXd xe = VectorXd::Constant(mat.rows(), 1);
 VectorXd b = mat*xe;

    
    SimplicialCholesky<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > chol(mat);
    VectorXd x = chol.solve(b); 

    double relative_error = (x-xe).norm()/(xe).norm(); 
    cout << relative_error << endl;
    
}
```

The matrix `ex15` can be downloaded from this [page](https://sparse.tamu.edu/FIDAP/ex15). It is a symmetric, positive definite matrix. Can anyone help me to solve the problem? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tested this on a much simpler matric with a known, expected result?

Comment: Hi Scott, ex15 matrix is a very simple sparse matrix. I use as benchmark Matlab's solution for the same system.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://sparse.tamu.edu/FIDAP/ex15), `ex15` is not full rank. You should check that each step went well:

```
SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > chol(mat);
if(chol.info()!=Eigen::Success)
  return;
VectorXd x = chol.solve(b); 
if(chol.info()!=Eigen::Success)
  return;
```

and then check that you got one solution (if it's not full rank and that at least one solution exists, then there exist a whole subspace of solutions):

```
cout << (mat*x-b).norm()/b.norm() << "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe I didn't explain my problem well. My code compute with success all steps but unfortunately I obtain a too high error. I also cannot understand 'cout << (mat*x-b).norm()/b.norm() << "\n";' this line of code. Can you explain your answer better? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `chol.info()` returns `Success`? You're trying to solve `Ax=b`, so `||Ax-b||` is the residual, aka error, and `||Ax-b||/||b||` is the relative error. If it's small enough, say 1e-15 for double, then you got a numerically valid solution to your problem.

Comment: ok, I just tried it, and `SimplicialLDLT::info()` does return `NumericalIssue`  after the numerical factorization which is expected since `ex15` is not numerically full rank. Also, `ex15.mtx` stores only the lower half triangle, so you have to use `mat.selfadjointView<Lower>() * vector` to apply it to a vector.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! With your last comment I succeeded in my goal. I have another question for you. How can I understand if .mtx stores just one half of the matrix? Thank you for your kindness.